# Meteor setup (boilerplate) with server-render and react-router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

I've only been developing with Meteor 1.4 for a while, and now made the jump to 1.6. Things sure have changed (for the worse).

Meteor used to be so easy to get started with. Now everything is a jumbled mess. It seems like every package wants to insert itself right at the start, so that you can't just import it and use it anymore, you have to change the setup/boilerplate of your app to get it to work. That also means the official documentation is useless because it can't account for every package you want to use.

Anyway, I want to get started with `react-router` and `server-render`, which also requires `react-helmet` (I think). All of these are new to me and hey, they want to insert themselves right away and they all have awful documentation to begin with.

Here's what I have so far, based on googling:

**`lib/main.js`:**

```
import React from 'react'

import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet'

import App from '../imports/ui/App.js'

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  import { hydrate } from 'react-dom'

  hydrate(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
}

else {
  import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server'
  import { onPageLoad } from 'meteor/server-render'
  import NodeCache from 'node-cache'

  const renderCache = new NodeCache({stdTTL: 432000})

  onPageLoad((sink) => {
    const path = sink.request.url.path
    let htmlString = renderCache.get(path)
    if (!htmlString) {
      htmlString = renderToString(<App location={path} />)
      const helmet = Helmet.renderStatic()

      renderCache.set(path, htmlString)
      renderCache.set(path + "_title", helmet.title.toString())
      renderCache.set(path + "_meta", helmet.meta.toString())
      renderCache.set(path + "_link", helmet.link.toString())
    }

    sink.appendToHead(renderCache.get(path + "_title"))
    sink.appendToHead(renderCache.get(path + "_meta"))
    sink.appendToHead(renderCache.get(path + "_link"))
    sink.renderIntoElementById("app", htmlString);
  })

}
```

And then `App.js` is just an empty component right now.

I don't know where to put my routing, or how (the docs assume you already know, for some reason). I think it also needs to insert itself in the `hydrate()` method on the client, but the example I got it from did not do that so I don't really know.

I don't know whether to put my `main.html` on the client or both client and server.

**I don't know how to set titles and meta tags and whatnot for each route.** (I thought this would actually be in the documentation for `react-helmet` since that's all it's supposed to do but no...)

Can anyone help me with the rest of this boilerplate? I have no idea what's going on in the Meteor world anymore.

Comment: Which react router? Meteor isn't the only one that has changed within that time.

Comment: @Jankapunkt It says 4.2.0